# Excel Formula to work out incremental figure defined by various monthly results

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, formula

I need a formula or VBA to help me calculate the below;

The base rate for a x sale will be £2.00 per sale
This will increase by 50p per sale if you deliver 100% attendance in the previous month to a maximum of £5.00 per sale.

Think im along the right lines with a ifand but I am struggling to create the formula to reset values if a poor month attendance is not achieved.

[example of sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXthZ.png)

New example[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yoric.png)

Comment: How do you record attendance? Is it a single flag to indicate attendance for a month, or are you expecting to iterate over a month's worth of data. More detail needed.

Comment: Hi, It will be based on e.g. a column (march) 100%, (feb) 79%, (jan) 100%.  Basically have the attendance figures and amount of sales to then generate the monetary value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it something like the following you need:

```
=J3*(2+MIN(3,(8-MAX(IF(B3:I3<>1,COLUMN(B3:I3)*1-1,0)))*0.5))
```

(Entered with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>.)

Update: If you don't want to reference the current (right-most) month in your calculation, use:

```
=J3*(2+MIN(3,(7-MAX(IF(B3:H3<>1,COLUMN(B3:H3)*1-1,0)))*0.5))
```

Comment: It does not work on the incremental basis of 50p per sale, or if a month is less than 100%

Comment: Is it just the one previous month that counts?

Comment: I've adjusted my answer.

Comment: It doesn't seem to reset fully if a month is under, for example I need it to go back to £2 as soon as the attendance is under 100% and then start again in the 50p increments, if the last month (current) is 100% but previous isn't this would be £2.  So basically rewards for consistent attendance.

Comment: So if the attendance record is 100,100,30,100,100,100,40,100, what would that result in?

Comment: the first month at 100% would always start at £2, then if following month 100%, 2.50 ect. until a month without 100% is missed, then starts again.  hope that makes sense

Comment: That's what my current formula is doing. :) If no months have 100%, it returns 16*2, if the previous 2 months have 100%, but then on the third previous month it was less, it returns 16*3, etc. (and it will never return more than 6*5).

Comment: I've put in the stats you put above and it returns as £40 (£2.50 per sale), but should be £32 (£2.00 per sale).  Regardless of the third month, if the last month is not 100% it needs to return to £2.

Comment: It's resulting the current month as £2.50 i think, having a play about with it

Comment: Yeah, when I say the third previous month, I'm working backwards. Basically, for every successive 100% on the right hand side (on the right of all <100% values), it adds on £0.50.

Comment: I think I know what you mean; I've added an update to my answer.

Comment: It does not seem to calculate correctly, when the amounts change the formula doesn't I've put the below together which might explain more clearly 
100,100,30,100,100,100,40,100 - Would result in £2.00 per sale
100,100,30,100,100,40,100,100 - Would result in £2.50 per sale
100,100,30,100,40,100,100,100 - Would result in £3.00 per sale
100,100,30,40,100,100,100,100 - Would result in £3.50 per sale
100,100,30,100,100,100,100,100 - Would result in £4.00 per sale
100,30,100,100,100,100,100,100 - Would result in £4.50 per sale
30,100,100,100,100,100,100,100 - Would result in £5.00 per sale

Comment: Are you using CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER to enter the formula (you also need to exclude the curly braces when you type it)?

Comment: Yep and it seems to be stuck or the £4 formula based on 100,100,30,100,100,100,40,100 but this should be £2?

Comment: I've seen your new example, the value 5 is relative to the columns you're using, I'll update my formula.

Comment: I've added a new example to the main post to show with the formula in, the result being shown and also what the result should be?

Comment: See above comment. :)

Comment: I have updated it again, it's tested and working now.